# Water Meter Suggestion for someone on well water?

Tags: plumbing, sprinkler-system, irrigation, water-meter

I am installing an underground waterline for irrigation by tapping into the home water line.  Since I have well water I don't have a water meter.  However, I would like to install a simple but accurate water meter (or similar type device) in the basement before the line exits the house so that I have peace of mind that there isn't a break in the water supply between my house and the garden faucet 160 feet away.  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Not VTC, but I think the question should be rephrased to ask about the actual problem, which is detecting a break in the outdoor water line.  Generally, post the problem, not your proposed solution.

Answer (score 1):

A definite solution to monitoring your line for leaks would be to install a meter.

If you google "water meter", you'll get a list of all different types.

Here is one I found after a quick search:

[image]

I'm not endorsing this product and have no affiliation with the company.

Comment: I would add a shutoff prior to the meter incase of problems in the future. That is a good price.